# Shorewall drop all incoming traffic from one internet IP except for all local host except two

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, shorewall

How i can block all incoming traffic from one internet IP for the local network, except for two host?

DROP            all        inet:78.31.8.0/24     -       -

The previous rule block all the incomming traffic from internet, but, how can allow the exception for two host?

Answer (score 0):

I resolv this with changing the source order:

```
DROP            local:!192.168.5.1,192.168.5.2        inet:78.31.8.0/24     -       -
```